# USB HID ATmega32u4 Arduino - system device ID / name changing from default Arduino Leonardo

Tags: keyboard, arduino, usb, device, hid

I'm building a USB HID device using Arduino Leonardo mini clone, based on **ATmega32u4**. That particular IC has got a USB controller built in, and turning it in to a HID device is simple. You just need to include `Keyboard.h` and then use `Keyboard.print`...

Where can I set/define the name of the device that is shown, when that Arduino is connected to a PC, because at the moment it is named Arduino Leonardo.

The default automated name for **tty** is **usbmodemHIDP1**.

In system preferences, I can see:

```
  ID product:     0x8036
  ID vendor:      0x2341
  Wersion:        1.00
  Serial number:  HIDPC
  Speed:          do 12 Mb/sek.
  Vendor:         Arduino LLC
  ID location:    0x14200000 / 16
```

So where in Arduino is file *Keyboard.h*? Can I change that name, or ID's?

Is it possible?

Because in my opinion it should be, but I just can't find the right place, and I do not have experience with Arduino AVR as I was working with Microchips Mplab X before for different ICs ;).

Comment: Do you have a vendor ID? Because you're not supposed to be changing that stuff unless you do.

Comment: Yes, i could use an existing Vendor ID from one of other devices also HID . I just do not want the prototype to be named Arduino leonardo, when listed in device manager. It may be just generic HID. Just I'm not sure where can i set it. In Keyboard.h or different sketch. The wiki for the Keyboard library on arduino site is extremely short, just listing the print/write functions, and i do not have much experience with Arduino, as before i was coding in Microchips mplab for different family of IC's.

Answer (score 1):

The "iProduct" string sent by the board on enumeration tells the operating system to give it the human-readable name. The value of that string is set near the top of USBCore.cpp in hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/. It's a Unicode string, so we need looking for 'L', 'e', 'o', 'n' [...], not "Leonardo". The string used depends on the PID number of the device (also sent during enumeration) which is given in boards.txt.

For distributing own custom hardware based on the Leonardo, there is a need to provide your own VID.

Also there can be used alternative firmware.
The Arduino '32U4 bootloader, Caterina, can be found under *hardware/arduino/bootloaders/caterina*. It requires [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php) in order to build.